# API and Their Endpoint Monitoring

Tags: monitor, health-monitoring

Say, there are 50 API's which are OAuth protected. What is the best way to monitor each and every one of those api's & their endpoint (say using synthetic transaction)? Please suggest some good open source tool to achieve the same.

Comment: Tool suggestions are off-topic for SO

Comment: ok, tools I can search out. If possible, can you please advise over logic/method to monitor large number of APIs?